# MySQL Select response missing rows with NULL values when <> used

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not getting what I need to get from a MySQL select query.  The response is missing all rows that have an attribute 'c2' that is NULL when I add a clause 'c2 <> 'A'.  I want those rows as well.  How can I change the query (Q2) to do this?

Here's the code that reproduces my issue.

```
CREATE  TABLE T (
`C1` VARCHAR(63) NOT NULL ,
`C2` VARCHAR(31) NULL);

INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Mike', 'A');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Mike', 'B');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Mike', 'C');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Mike', NULL);
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Mark', 'C');
INSERT INTO T VALUES ('Mark', NULL);
```

## Q1:

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE C1 = 'Mike';
```

Returned values are as I expected:

- 'Mike', 'A'
- 'Mike', 'B'
- 'Mike', 'C'
- 'Mike', NULL

## Q2:

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE C1 = 'Mike' AND C2 <> 'A';
```

Returned values are NOT as I expected:
 - 'Mike', 'B'
 - 'Mike', 'C'

## MISSING: ('Mike', NULL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the expected results, adjust your query to the following: ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e445/5))

```
SELECT * FROM T WHERE C1 = 'Mike' AND (C2 <> 'A' OR C2 IS NULL);
```

To answer the question of why the query is not returning the expected values with the not equal operator, this [article](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html) provides a good explanation.

Basically:

> To test for NULL, use the IS NULL and IS NOT NULL operators ...
>   You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as =, <, or <> to test for NULL.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM T WHERE C1 = 'Mike' AND COALESCE(C2, '') <> 'A';` seems better peformance wise